# Intranet for mobile application

Tags: android, iphone, intranet

I have been given the task to create an intranet application for my company that needs to be able to run on iPhone and Android. The current intranet that are running on the web have 1500 users, now not all of these will be downloading the application, but I am counting on this number just to be on the safe side. 
I have already asked about creating a website that fits a mobile screen and so on and these ideas have all been rejected. I have done some research trying to figure out how to do this the best way and I have a few question to you guys.

I have already cleared it with my boss that the iPhone application will use the enterprise license (https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Will this license make it possible for us to select who can download the application on the app store?

Is there a similar license that I need to buy for Android?

Do you guys in general have any advice on creating such applications?

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is rolling out an enterprise area of Google Play to allow for exact this scenario, but of course that relies on the company be using Google Enterprise services http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/12/04/google-play-comes-to-google-apps-letting-enterprise-customers-distribute-apps-internally/

Appart from that, remember that Android devices can install apps from anywhere, no need to be unlocked, rooted, jailbroken or anything like this.

You can just make the app available on the intranet website and make an API for update cheking,

Comment: Is this still true? Can Android devices still install an APK from anywhere without any rooting? Is this true across all Android devices?

Comment: Yes @josh, it didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You cant regulate who can download app from appstore in iphone,although you can specify the region where your app should be download and where it will not be download.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Is there a way to distribute the iphone application without using the App Store now that I have the Enterprise license?

Comment: not in my knowledge, but yes you can use your app without using app store in jailbroken devices.